# Internal server based on nanomsg

Tags: go, zeromq, nanomsg

I'm learning nanomsg and zeromq these days with Golang binding. I've tested with Req-Rep which can work, but is it a proper idea to use this mechanism to build reliable internal server for serving data under high concurrent requests (but from limited client sources < 30)?

Some pseudo code may looks like,

```
for {
    data, conn = socketRep.readData()
    go func(data, conn){
        result=process(data)
        conn.sendReply(result)
        conn.close()
    }()
}
```

How to achieve similar communication pattern in nanomsg? Is there any example (C is ok) available?

====UPDATE====

Sorry the question looks too broad. The most important question for me is, "Is there any workable Req/Rep example (C is ok) around?"

Answer (score 2):

### The VERY first thing one shall know when deciding on "*How to build* Reliable Server ... for serving high concurrent load"

Learning any new library is thrilling and makes a lot of new insights.

One very important insight is to ***undertake*** just right-sized & REASONABLE challenges alongside one's own learning-curve trajectory.

**If Pieter Hintjens**, co-father of the ZeroMQ, **has written** [ almost in bold ] the **following remarks** right upon entering into a chapter on designing any RELIABLE SERVICE, he **knew pretty well WHY to precede forthcoming paragraphs on such designs with a similar highlighted warning...**

- (cit.:) " ... going to get into unpleasantly complex territory here
  that has me getting up for another espresso. You should appreciate
  that making "reliable" messaging is complex enough that **you always
  need to ask**, "do we actually need  this?" before jumping into it.
  If you can get away with unreliable, or "good enough" reliability,
  you **can make a huge win in terms of cost and complexity**. Sure,
  you may lose some data now and then. It is often a good trade-off.
  ..."

---

### Nanomsg is out of doubts a great & smart library Project

**The high-level philosophy thoughts** brought from Pieter Hintjens books on advanced designs, that build "beyond the elementary ZeroMQ" Scaleable Formal Communication Patterns **remains much the same**

IMHO it is best to spend a few more weeks on ideas and design-paradigms & stories in both Pieter Hintjens' books, before moving into any coding.

Both a 400+ pages book **The ZeroMQ Guide - for Python Developers, Section II., Advanced ZeroMQ**, ( namely Chapters 6.2, 6.7,  7.1 and 7.5 )

and

a 300+ pages book **"Code Connected Volume 1"**, ( namely the process of adding reliability  in Chapter 5 - be it for the sake of reliability per-se or also for the sake of unlocking next levels of performace via load-balancing over a pool-of-resources )

will help anyone to start exploring this great but thrilling field of distributed system architecture & will help get perspectives needed for designing surviveable aproaches without re-exploring many dead-ends, that have already been proved to be dead-ends.